# Storing dates with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to store a date with Laravel. I have a `timestamp` field (but I have tried with a `date` field with the same issue) and whenever I try to store a date with the format `dd-mm-yyyy` it stores `date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"`. Here is how I am storing the date:

```
$result = new Result();
$result->date = Carbon::parse(Request::input('date'));
```

(along with all the over vars and `$result->save();`)

I have the `date` field in my `$dates` variable in my `Result` model.

If anyone could tell me why it does this it would be awesome!

Thanks

**Edit:** When I do `var_dump` on `Request::input('date')` I get `string(10) "15-06-2015"`

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump(Carbon::parse(Request::input('date')))`?

Comment: That is weird, its supposed to be an object not a string. Can you try `var_dump(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', Request::input('date'))`?

Comment: That creates a `Carbon` instance, looks like this:
`Carbon {#257 ▼
  +"date": "2015-06-15 10:19:17.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Pacific/Auckland"
}`

However, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, if you save that to the database in a date or datetime fieldtype it should work. so `$result->date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', Request::input('date')`

Comment: Ah nevermind, read your edit too late

Comment: Fixed, I forgot something that was pretty stupid. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I put the `date` field in my `$dates` field in my Model, I took it out of my `$fillable`. Thanks for everyones help!